# How to do an Interleaved Sort in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do an exception report to show the differences in total amounts between two modules in an application we have.  So, I have two tables, #TranSum and #ModSum.  Both have a similar very basic structure of an ID field and an Amount field.  Almost all the transactions in #TranSum and #ModSum are going to be the same but I am looking for the few records where there is an amount for an ID in #TranSum with no equivalent in #ModSum (or vice versa) or there are matching IDs but the amounts are different.  For example:

#TranSum

| ID | Amt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 4 | 200 |
| 5 | 50 |
| 6 | 700 |
| 8 | 25 |

#ModSum

| ID | Amt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 31 |
| 3 | 200 |
| 5 | 50 |
| 7 | 700 |
| 8 | 25 |

As you can see in the above, ID#s 1,5, and 8 are the same in both tables.  However, 2 has a different amount (30 in one table and 31 in the other) and 3, 4, 6, and 7 only exist in one table or the other.  I am looking for a query that would give me something like this:

| #TranSum.ID | #TranSum.Amt | #ModSum.ID | #ModSum.Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 30 | 2 | 31 |
|  |  | 3 | 200 |
| 4 | 200 |  |  |
|  |  | 6 | 700 |
| 7 | 700 |  |  |

Basically I am trying to do something like this:

```
select t.ID, t.Amt, m.ID, m.Amt
from #TranSum t full outer join #ModSum m on t.ID = m.ID
where isnull(t.Amt,0) <> isnull(m.Amt, 0)
```

But I don't know how I can sort it on the interleaved IDs of the two tables.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The sorting part is probably just `ORDER BY COALESCE(t.ID, m.ID)` on the premise that one of them is always non-null, or they are the same value.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @topsail - Thanks!  This is exactly what I needed!  Can you make this an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can just sort by `ISNULL(t.ID, m.ID)`. Note that `ISNULL` is favoured in SQL Server over `COALESCE` because it is understood better by the compiler.

Also, the `WHERE` clause should properly take account of nulls, as `0` and `null` are not the same.

```sql
select
  t.ID,
  t.Amt,
  m.ID,
  m.Amt
from #TranSum t
full outer join #ModSum m on t.ID = m.ID
where t.Amt is distinct from m.Amt
order by
  isnull(t.ID, m.ID);
```

If you are on an older version of SQL Server then you can use `where t.Amt <> m.Amt or t.Amt is null or m.Amt is null` instead.

Comment: `IS DISTINCT FROM` is now implemented in SQL Server? Wow...

Comment: Thanks!  This also works the same as the coalesce(t.ID,m.ID) as suggested by @the-impaler. I've never seen the IS DISTINCT FROM clause before!

Comment: Just tested IS DISTINCT FROM and is available in SQL Server 2022 and newer. This is good.

Comment: When in doubt check the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 "Applies to: SQL Server 2022 (16.x) Azure SQL Database Azure SQL Managed Instance SQL analytics endpoint in Microsoft Fabric Warehouse in Microsoft Fabric"

Answer (score 1):

The natural solution for this case is a full outer join. You can do:

```sql
select
  t.id as transum_id, t.amt as transum_amt,
  u.id as modsum_id, u.amt as modsum_amt  
from t
full join u on u.id = t.id
where u.amt <> t.amt or u.amt is null or t.amt is null
order by coalesce(t.id, u.id)
```

Result:

```
 transum_id  transum_amt  modsum_id  modsum_amt 
 ----------- ------------ ---------- ---------- 
 2           30           2          31         
 null        null         3          200        
 4           200          null       null       
 6           700          null       null       
 null        null         7          700
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PXYiIF0E).

Comment: This is what I have already but the sort order is the problem.

Comment: Added the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks!  @charlieface was first so I have to give the answer to him.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following solution.

IMHO, it has a better more generic and clear output for comparison. It will support multi-column tables for comparison.

If needed it is easy to modify the SQL `SELECT` statement to output blank values instead of NULLs.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @TranSum TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Amt INT);
DECLARE @ModSum TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Amt INT);

INSERT INTO @TranSum (ID, Amt) VALUES
(1, 15 ),
(2, 30 ),
(4, 200),
(5, 50 ),
(6, 700),
(8, 25 );

INSERT INTO @ModSum (ID, Amt) VALUES
(1, 15 ),
(2, 31 ),
(3, 200),
(5, 50 ),
(7, 700),
(8, 25 )
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT Src = 1
        , ID 
        , c.value('local-name(.)','SYSNAME') AS [Key]
        , c.value('text()[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Value]
    FROM @TranSum AS t
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(x)
        CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/root/*') AS t2(c)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Src = 2
        , ID 
        , c.value('local-name(.)','SYSNAME') AS [Key]
        , c.value('text()[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Value]
    FROM @ModSum AS t
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(x)
        CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/root/*') AS t2(c)
)
SELECT ID
    , [key] AS [column]
    , TranSum_Value = MAX(CASE WHEN Src = 1 THEN Value END)
    , ModSum_Value = MAX(CASE WHEN Src = 2 THEN Value END)
FROM rs
GROUP BY ID, [key]
HAVING COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Src = 1 THEN Value END),'')
     <> COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Src = 2 THEN Value END),'')
ORDER BY ID,[key];
```

**Output**

| ID | column | TranSum_Value | ModSum_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Amt | 30 | 31 |
| 3 | Amt | NULL | 200 |
| 3 | ID | NULL | 3 |
| 4 | Amt | 200 | NULL |
| 4 | ID | 4 | NULL |
| 6 | Amt | 700 | NULL |
| 6 | ID | 6 | NULL |
| 7 | Amt | NULL | 700 |
| 7 | ID | NULL | 7 |

Comment: Thanks.  This is a more standard IT type exception report but I don't need anything this complex or versatile.  I only need this report to compare these two particular tables and I think my format above is much more readable as it is very easy to see where one value is missing from one side or the other.